# KDEInit could not launch /usr/bin/kate

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.11.1 and the rootactions service menu in Dolphin.

I opened Dolphin as root then clicked on a text file. I got a "Sorry" dialog with the message:

```
KDEInit could not launch /usr/bin/kate
```

So I opened a terminal and issued this command as root:

```
# /usr/bin/kate
```

That worked and Kate opened as expected.

Why is Dolphin giving this error and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the rootactions service menu then you could launch the text editor with the  root rights from the normal Dolphin window. An older Kubuntu forums topic: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58679-Kate-won-t-start-from-Dolphin-as-root

Comment: I cannot access the directory containing the file from the normal Dolphin window due to directory permissions, so that won't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved by the latest update to Root Actions Servicemenu (version 2.8).

KDE Service Menu - Root Actions Servicemenu
http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=48411

Comment: This seems to be a bit of a red herring to me, as the problem is not strictly related to root actions. It can happen also with when opening kate as a user.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same option after upgrading to Kubuntu 15.04.

Fixed by opening the file

```
.local/share/applications/kde4-kate.desktop
```

And changing the line:

`X-DBUS-StartupType=Multi`

to

`X-DBUS-StartupType=none`

Which fixed the error for me. Got the idea from [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=64167) and it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue with newly released Kubuntu 15.04 (Vivid). I resolved it by replacing the command in the link `kate -u %U` with `kate -b %U`.

According to kate's docs, the option `-u`, `--use` tells kate to

> Use an already running Kate instance; default, only for compatibility.

Kate in this release says the option is unknown. Option `-b`, `--block` tells kate to

> If using an already running Kate instance, block until it exits, if URLs given to open.